# Backup/Restore a dockerized PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, docker

I'm trying to backup/restore a PostgreSQL database as is explained on the Docker website, but the data is not restored.

The volumes used by the database image are:

```
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

and the CMD is:

```
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

I create the DB container with this command:

```
docker run -it --name "$DB_CONTAINER_NAME" -d "$DB_IMAGE_NAME"
```

Then I connect another container to insert some data manually:

```
docker run -it --rm --link "$DB_CONTAINER_NAME":db "$DB_IMAGE_NAME" sh -c 'exec bash'
psql -d test -h $DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR
# insert some data in the db
<CTRL-D>
<CTRL-D>
```

The tar archive is then created:

```
$ sudo docker run --volumes-from "$DB_CONTAINER_NAME" --rm -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /etc/postgresql /var/log/postgresql /var/lib/postgresql
```

Now I remove the container used for the db and create another one, with the same name, and try to restore the data inserted before:

```
$ sudo docker run --volumes-from "$DB_CONTAINER_NAME" --rm -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar xvf /backup/backup.tar
```

But the tables are empty, why is the data not properly restored ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215489/538284

Answer (score 954, accepted):

### Backup your databases

```
docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql
```

Creates filename like `dump_2023-12-25_09_15_26.sql`

If you want a smaller file size, use gzip:

```
docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U postgres | gzip > dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql.gz
```

If you want even smaller file sizes use `brotli` or `bzip2`:

```
docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U postgres | brotli --best > dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql.br
```

or

```
docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U postgres | bzip2 --best > dump_`date +%Y-%m-%d"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql.bz2
```

### Restore your databases

```
cat your_dump.sql | docker exec -i your-db-container psql -U postgres
```

Comment: Yep, that's the postgres way to do it, but I think the docker way should always be prefered when you use it

Comment: To save some space on disk you might want to pipe the dump to gzip:

`docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U postgres | gzip > /var/data/postgres/backups/dump_`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S`.gz`

Comment: @Tarion How can I restore `.xz` or  `.gz` packed this way?

Comment: Just unzip the data before you restore it. To do it as a one liner you will have to replace the `cat your_dump.sql` with the unzip command and pipe that instead of the `cat` result to docker exec.

Comment: when I run the backup command it says **"docker exec" requires at least 2 argument(s).**

Comment: I'm running Docker on Windows and this works fine.  But I'm wondering... what would a regular backup schedule look like?  I don't even want to lose my data.

Comment: Problem with this approach is providing the password. If the password prompt is displayed the backup will fail. But it's possible to provide password through postgres ENV variables.

Comment: The date format is messed up, so double check that before you copy and paste.

Comment: Docker is often an insidious, low quality, leaky abstraction over running processes. I struggled to do this simple task for over an hour, and the answer is something that's never used in a normal postgres flow, which we have to do because docker doesn't support better command execution.

Comment: For those would couldn't figure out how to get the date formatting working:

`docker exec -t your-db-container  pg_dumpall -c -U postgres | gzip > ./tmp/dump_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S").gz`

Comment: When restoring the database, make sure you add `-d your-db-name` to the restore command **if** your database isn't named `postgres`.

Comment: With the given commands, you may run into an ugly surprise if your DB contains UTF-8 characters. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934856/why-is-pg-restore-segfaulting-in-docker) for more details and a solution.

Comment: 'gzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on Windows.

Comment: looks like this may produce some problem with encodings, I've got ????? instead of some cyrillics texts

Comment: Note: For `docker-compose` users, that's `docker-compose exec -T` (capital T)

Comment: How do we use this approach with DB volumes?
I currently have the following volume for my PostgreSQL container;
`
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql
`

Comment: @AndyRay at any time you can `docker exec -it ${container_name} bash -il` and break into a fully functional CLI for postgres.  Any work can be saved with `docker commit`.  Any files can be copied with `docker cp`.  A LOT has changed in the 4 years since your comment.

Comment: when restoring im facing this issue 
``` ERROR:  database "template1" does not exist
\connect: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "template1" does not exist ```

Answer (score 118):

## Backup Database

generate sql:

- `docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U your-db-user > dump_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S).sql`

to reduce the size of the sql you can generate a compress:

- `docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U your-db-user | gzip > ./dump_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S").gz`

## Restore Database

- `cat your_dump.sql | docker exec -i your-db-container psql -U your-db-user -d your-db-name`

to restore a compressed sql:

- `gunzip < your_dump.sql.gz | docker exec -i your-db-container psql -U your-db-user -d your-db-name`

*PD: this is a compilation of what worked for me, and what I got from here and elsewhere. I am beginning to make contributions, any feedback will be appreciated.*

Comment: using "cat your_dump.sql | .... " to restore a db  I think has a really low performance, am I wrong?

Comment: You forgot a sql extension before gz: docker exec -t your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U your-db-user | gzip > ./dump_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S").sql.gz

Comment: Scenario: `user` table has 2 users. We make a backup. We register another user, so table has 3 entries. We restore backup with `cat your_dump.sql | docker exec -i your-db-container psql -U your-db-user -d your-db-name`. Result: user table still has 3 entries; backup did not restore database state at backup. P.s. I'm beginner too, maybe I hold incorrect assumptions how backups work.

Answer (score 87):

I think you can also use a postgres backup container which would backup your databases within a given time duration.

```
  pgbackups:
    container_name: Backup
    image: prodrigestivill/postgres-backup-local
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./backup:/backups
    links:
      - db:db
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME} 
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_EXTRA_OPTS=-Z9 --schema=public --blobs
      - SCHEDULE=@every 0h30m00s
      - BACKUP_KEEP_DAYS=7
      - BACKUP_KEEP_WEEKS=4
      - BACKUP_KEEP_MONTHS=6
      - HEALTHCHECK_PORT=81
```

Comment: How exaclty do you run this command? new to docker etc

Comment: This isn't a command @JackB, it's a `docker-compose` file. https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Yes. correct just use this to insert in your docker-compose file and then run the docker-compose file

Comment: @TharinduPradeep Thanks. I can see the container but where do the backups go?

Comment: Does this actually work without downtime? How does the container deal with changes that occur while it's creating the backup?

Comment: @AneeshPanoli to /backups folder defined at  - ./backup:/backups

Comment: Incredibly useful for people who want to automatically backup their DB at regular intervals.

Comment: How to restore the backup?

Answer (score 47):

`cat db.dump | docker exec ...` way didn't work for my dump (~2Gb). It took few hours and ended up with out-of-memory error.

Instead, I cp'ed dump into container and pg_restore'ed it from within.

Assuming that container id is `CONTAINER_ID` and db name is `DB_NAME`:

```sh
# copy dump into container
docker cp local/path/to/db.dump CONTAINER_ID:/db.dump

# shell into container
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash

# restore it from within
pg_restore -U postgres -d DB_NAME --no-owner -1 /db.dump
```

Comment: this approach, unlike the accepted one, helped me to get correct encodings when doing this in Windows. (Actually, I applied the dump by going `cat /home/db.sql | psql -U postgres -d DB_NAME -p DB_PORT`)

Comment: This works much faster. One could make a backupscript based on this, build an image with the script included, and fire the script from the host through a cronjob. Mount a host-volume onto the container, and have  a backupserver pull the daily sql-dumps.

Comment: I appreciate this because I had the exact same problem with `cat db.dum |...`

Answer (score 13):

Okay, I've figured this out. Postgresql does not detect changes to the folder /var/lib/postgresql once it's launched, at least not the kind of changes I want it do detect.

The first solution is to start a container with bash instead of starting the postgres server directly, restore the data, and then start the server manually.

The second solution is to use a data container. I didn't get the point of it before, now I do.
This data container allows to restore the data before starting the postgres container. Thus, when the postgres server starts, the data are already there.

Comment: flocker or convoy might help with data container dealing.

Comment: Please fill in more details. This sounds more like a sketch of a solution than an actual solution

Answer (score 13):

The below command can be used to take dump from docker postgress container

```
docker exec -t <postgres-container-name> pg_dump --no-owner -U <db-username> <db-name> > file-name-to-backup-to.sql
```

Comment: Caution: I experienced a broken backup file when I used `pg_dump -F c` (custom format) with the `docker exec -t` option. I assume the terminal mode interferes with the piped binary output. Do not use `docker exec -t` (or `-i`).

Answer (score 9):

The top answer didn't work for me. I kept getting this error:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

To get it to work I had to specify a user for the docker container:

#### Backup

```
docker exec -t --user postgres your-db-container pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > dump_`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql
```

#### Restore

```
cat your_dump.sql | docker exec -i --user postgres your-db-container psql -U postgres
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach (based on [docker-postgresql-workflow](https://davidamick.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/docker-postgresql-workflow/))

Local running database (not in docker, but same approach would work) to export:

```
pg_dump -F c -h localhost mydb -U postgres export.dmp
```

Container database to import:

```
docker run -d -v /local/path/to/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres #ex runs container as `CONTAINERNAME` #find via `docker ps`
docker run -it --link CONTAINERNAME:postgres  --volume $PWD/:/tmp/  postgres  bash -c 'exec pg_restore -h postgres -U postgres -d mydb -F c /tmp/sonar.dmp'
```

Comment: this worked for me: `pg_dump mydb -U postgres > export.psql` in docker container bash

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue while trying to use a db_dump to restore a db. I normally use dbeaver to restore- however received a psql dump, so had to figure out a method to restore using the docker container.

The methodology recommended by Forth and edited by Soviut worked for me:

`cat your_dump.sql | docker exec -i your-db-container psql -U postgres -d dbname`

(since this was a single db dump and not multiple db's i included the name)

However, in order to get this to work, I had to also go into the virtualenv that the docker container and project were in. This eluded me for a bit before figuring it out- as I was receiving the following docker error.

`read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer`

This can be caused by the file  /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db .I don't know the accuracy of this statement: but I believe I was seeing this as I do not user docker locally, so therefore did not have this file, which it was looking for, using Forth's answer.

I then navigated to correct directory (with the project) activated the virtualenv and then ran the accepted answer. Boom, worked like a top. Hope this helps someone else out there!

Answer (score 3):

`dksnap` (https://github.com/kelda/dksnap) automates the process of running `pg_dumpall` and loading the dump via `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

It shows you a list of running containers, and you pick which one you want to backup. The resulting artifact is a regular Docker image, so you can then `docker run` it, or share it by pushing it to a Docker registry.

(disclaimer: I'm a maintainer on the project)

Comment: great! looking forward for "A non-graphical CLI interface that's scriptable." so that I can use it from Robot Framework tests :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the command worked for me.

```
cat your_dump.sql | sudo docker exec -i {docker-postgres-container} psql -U {user} -d {database_name}
```

for example

```
cat table_backup.sql | docker exec -i 03b366004090 psql -U postgres -d postgres
```

*Reference*: Solution given by ***GMartinez-Sisti*** in this discussion.
https://gist.github.com/gilyes/525cc0f471aafae18c3857c27519fc4b

Comment: I am getting back `invalid command \N` in the terminal when i run the command `cat your_dump.sql | sudo docker exec -i {docker-postgres-container} psql -U {user} -d {database_name}
`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to run the pg_restore (of course if you have postgres set up in your host machine) command from the host machine.

Assuming that you have port mapping "5436:5432" for the postgres service in your docker-compose file. Having this port mapping will let you access the container's postgres (running on port 5432) via your host machine's port 5436

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5436 -U <POSTGRES_USER> -d <POSTGRES_DB>  /Path/to/the/.psql/file/in/your/host_machine
```

This way you do not have to dive into the container's terminal or copy the dump file to the container.

Answer (score 1):

Using a File System Level Backup on Docker Volumes

### Example Docker Compose

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: platerecognizer/parkpow-postgres
    # restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: admin

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

### Backup Postgresql Volume

```
docker run --rm \
   --user root \
   --volumes-from pg_container \
   -v /tmp/db-bkp:/backup \
   ubuntu tar cvf /backup/db.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Then copy `/tmp/db-bkp` to second host

### Restore Postgresql Volume

```
docker run --rm \
   --user root \
   --volumes-from pg_container \
   -v /tmp/db-bkp:/backup \
   ubuntu bash -c "cd /var && tar xvf /backup/db.tar --strip 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for `docker-compose` users:

1. At First run the docker-compose file by any on of following commands: `$ docker-compose -f loca.yml up` OR `docker-compose -f loca.yml up -d`
2. For taking backup: `$ docker-compose -f local.yml exec postgres backup`
3. To see list of backups inside container: `$ docker-compose -f local.yml exec postgres backups`
4. Open another terminal and run following command: `$ docker ps`
5. Look for the **CONTAINER ID** of `postgres` image and copy the ID. Let's assume the **CONTAINER ID** is: ***ba78c0f9bcee***
6. Now to bring that backup into your local file system, run the following command: `$ docker cp ba78c0f9bcee:/backups ./local_backupfolder`

Hope this will help someone who was lost just like me..

N.B: The full details of this solution can be found [here](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker-postgres-backups.html#creating-a-backup).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me. This could be helpful if you're trying to do this the docker way.

1. **STOP the DB_CONTAINER**

   ```
   docker stop DB_CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME
   ```
2. **BACKUP DB data**

   ```
   docker run --rm 
   --user root 
   --volumes-from DB_CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME 
   -v /path/to/local_storage:/backup 
   ubuntu tar cvf /backup/db.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data
   ```
3. **MOVE** your backup file that's stored in your `/path/to/local_storage` in any other server or your local host
4. **RESTORE DB DATA**

   ```
   docker run --rm 
     --user root 
     --volumes-from DB_CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME 
     -v /path/to/local_storage:/backup 
     ubuntu bash -c "cd /var && tar xvf /backup/db.tar --strip 1"
   ```
5. **START THE DB_CONTAINER**

   ```
   docker start
   ```

Comment: Please use markdown to highlight the syntax accordingly, e.g. backticks `this is code`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the official docker documentation for [backups and restores](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).  This applies to all kinds of data within a volume, not just postegres.

> ### Backup a container
>
> Create a new container named dbstore:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -v /dbdata --name dbstore ubuntu /bin/bash
> ```
>
> Then in the next command, we:
>
> - Launch a new container and mount the volume from the dbstore container
> - Mount a local host directory as /backup
> - Pass a command that tars the contents of the dbdata volume to a backup.tar file inside our /backup directory.
>
>   $ docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
>
> When the command completes and the container stops, we are left with a backup of our dbdata volume.
>
> ### Restore container from backup
>
> With the backup just created, you can restore it to the same container, or another that you made elsewhere.
>
> For example, create a new container named dbstore2:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -v /dbdata --name dbstore2 ubuntu /bin/bash
> ```
>
> Then un-tar the backup file in the new container`s data volume:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
> ```
>
> You can use the techniques above to automate backup, migration and restore testing using your preferred tools.

Answer (score 0):

### Main 2 steps:

1. Get docker container name with `docker ps`. You will get something like:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       ...   PORTS                                         NAMES
b36b6a66659f   postgres    ...   0.0.0.0:5066->5432/tcp, :::5066->5432/tcp     my-db
```

2. And create a dump for `my-db` to local path:

```bash
docker exec -i my-db pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:DB_PASSWORD@localhost:5432/postgres > ./my_db_dump.sql
```

*For someone it can be helpful to know dbname schema:*

```
postgresql://DB_USER:DB_PASSWORD@DB_HOST:5432/DB_NAME
```

### Another related and useful commands:

To run sql command within container:

```bash
docker exec -i my-db psql -U postgres --dbname postgres -c "select * from users"
```

To restore dump:

```bash
cat ./my_db_dump.sql | docker exec -i my-db psql -U postgres
```