# Postgres pg_dump Error

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U user_name database_name | psql -h 10.590.8.46 -U user_name database_name
```

I am trying to dump a database to a remote server on linux, and this is the error I keep getting:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "database_name" failed:   
FATAL:  invalid command-line argument for server process: -I
HINT:  Try "postgres --help" for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce this behavior is by setting the `PGOPTIONS` environment variable:

```
export PGOPTIONS=-I
```

Check if that variable is set, and if yes, unset it with

```
unset PGOPTIONS
```

Comment: This worked, and now with a different error.  

    pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for 
    relation portal_audit_log_tb
    pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE 
    public.portal_audit_log_tb IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

Comment: The database user used for `pg_dump` must at least have `SELECT` privileges for all dumped objects.

Comment: permission denied for relation portal_blacklist_det_tb is what I get for the pg_dump user. NB: This was the user that created the database!

Comment: It might have been the user that created the database, but it still has no `SELECT` privileges on the table. Try to `SELECT` from the table as that database user!

Comment: Thank you, works when I run it as the postgres user.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this post [pg_dump postgres database from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648309/pg-dump-postgres-database-from-remote-server)

the command to dump the database from remote is

```
ssh user@remote_machine "pg_dump -U dbuser -h localhost database_name " \
 >> backup_file_on_your_local_machine.sql
```

Comment: This answer seems irrelevant to the problem.