# Why is pg_restore segfaulting in Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, backup, database-backups

I am testing a backup/restore procedure for my postgres DB inside a docker container.

I dump my db like this:

```
$ docker exec -ti my_postgres_container pg_dump -Fc -U postgres > db.dump
```

Afterwards, I try to restore it like this:

```
$ docker cp db.dump my_postgres_container:/db.dump
$ docker exec -ti my_postgres_container pg_restore -U postgres -c -d postgres db.dump
```

The command returns without output or errors, but nothing happens.

So instead, I tried to restore it manually like this:

```
$ docker cp db.dump my_postgres_container:/db.dump
$ docker exec -ti my_postgres_container bash
root@fdaad610bee3:/# pg_restore -U postgres -c -d postgres db.dump
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is pg_restore segfaulting when trying to read my DB dump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: `-t` should not be used unnecessarily.

I think for your pg_dump, the `-t` is corrupting the data written to db.dump. For that matter, the `-i` is also redundant since pg_dump does not need to read from stdin.

For your pg_restore, you need neither option. If you redirect stdin from outside the container, then you need `-i`.

I had the same problem and solved it by using neither `-i` nor `-t` for the pg_dump.

I think the following fixed pg_dump should work for your case:

```
$ docker exec my_postgres_container pg_dump -Fc -U postgres -d postgress > db.dump
```

Incidentally for the pg_restore, you don't need to copy the dump file to the container. You can just redirect stdin from the dump file on the host:

```
$ docker exec -i my_postgres_container pg_restore -Fc -c -U postgres -d postgres < db.dump
```

Answer (score 26):

**Analysis:**

The problem is caused by a corruption when dumping the DB. `pg_dump` produces binary output. This output is first passed through the Docker container's `stdout` and then redirected into a file on the host. Somewhere on the way, non-ASCII bytes are corrupted.

**Solution:**

Let `pg_dump` write to a *file inside the Docker container*, then copy that out to the host:

correct dumping procedure:

```
docker exec -ti my_postgres_container bash -c 'pg_dump -Fc -U postgres > /db.dump'
docker cp my_postgres_container:/db.dump db.dump
```

correct restoring procedure:

```
docker cp db.dump my_postgres_container:/db.dump
docker exec -ti my_postgres_container pg_restore -U postgres -c -d postgres db.dump
```

Answer (score 2):

For those like me that have the corrupt dump and can't follow the accepted answer, I found a [workaround here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADgu3M8Vw4XPf2uM4dHuMyJ6721APBgSaDiUopdFKsRRVEByCg%40mail.gmail.com)

> The dump file's format is DOS when you open with vim,
> and if you change this to unix (`:set ff=unix`) and save it,
> the segmentation fault will go
> away

And that does works.