# Hasura & PostgreSQL - Move data between instances

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean, hasura

I used the 1-click digital ocean deployment from [the docs](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/deployment/deployment-guides/digital-ocean-one-click.html#step-1-create-a-hasura-one-click-droplet) to create a Hasura instance. I then configured Hasura, created tables, added rows etc. and got the data model for my app all worked out.

I now need to move all this data to a separate Digital Ocean volume `/mnt/volume_hasura` so I can increase the storage space as the database grows. I created a new Hasura instance on the same droplet, from inside the new volume, and I can access that on a different port. How do I transfer all data and config from one instance of Hasura to another? I get that Hasura doesn't store the actual data, the underlying PostgreSQL database stores it, but I haven't been able to find how to transfer the database **and** the config together.

At the moment I've got both instances of Hasura running at the same time, on the same droplet, and I can access both of them via the web interface. It appears they both use different databases but I've been unable to locate where these databases **are**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with Hasura, there is a thing called "metadata", it is the way Hasura store the database relations, permissons and so on. You can export/import this via Hasura Console.

On the database side, you need to do import/export by yourself. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718706/backup-restore-a-dockerized-postgresql-database) is a good example.

Comment: You can also use RepliByte (github.com/Qovery/replibyte) to backup your Postgres instance and restore it to another one. It's exactly built for this purpose. It's fast (written in Rust) and open-source.