# Restore sql file to a postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm new with docker and i have to learn at my new job, so i should restore a sql file into a postgres container, when i type the command:

```sh
docker exec -i postgres-container pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/data/_postgres_2020-11-09T02_00_06Z.sql
```

i get the following message:

```
pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

After that i tried to convert that file with psql inside the container but i get this message:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist.
```

How can i get this? can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! activereality's answer solve my problem in this post [Backup/Restore a dockerized PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718706/backup-restore-a-dockerized-postgresql-database)

cat your_dump.sql | docker exec -i your-db-container psql -U postgres -d dbname

Comment: or `docker exec -i your-db-container psql -U postgres -d dbname < your_dump.sql` I guess