# Access sql dump inside docker container django postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Django with Postgres database so I've created separate docker containers for Django and Postgres, now I want to share the dump file with my team but I'm unable to access the dump file, please let me know how can I access the dump file and after accessing it how can we import it using the container?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  pgdb:
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

location inside db docker container

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718706/backup-restore-a-dockerized-postgresql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it using docker [`cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) utility

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
```

But rather  than doing that you can directly pipe output of pg_dump

```
docker exec -t container pg_dump ... > dump.sql
```

and import

```
cat dump.sql | docker exec -i container psql ...
```

Comment: how would I import that dump inside the same container on another system?