# How to restore postgres dump through pgadmin docker container (dockerized postgres)

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

Dear stackoverflowers,

I use docker-compose to run the dockerized postgresql server and dockerized pgadmin4 webserver.
When i try to restore a dump via the web interface it shows me an empty folder with the path "/" for source location of the dump.

Now my question, is it in general possible to restore a dump via dockerized pgadmin and if, what path from which container (postgres or pgadmin) do i have to mount as volume to provide the dump to be restored?

```
    version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres:12.10
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ***
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ***
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
```

With kind regards
starguy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718706/backup-restore-a-dockerized-postgresql-database

Comment: @iLuvLogix your link does not talk about pgAdmin at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation as you are. In the web pgadmin, you have an option to upload a .sql file just by clicking at the ... button.

[image: pgadmin4 upload image]