# back up and restore postgres docker with data

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have postgres docker server `postgres:9.6.24`, I planned to copy the docker container with all of the database and its data to another laptop.

So, I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29913462).

But after restored the database in another laptop, I got only the structure of the database. It has all the tables without any data/records/rows

How to backup and restore the postgres docker server to another computer

Comment: You could try to help those you want to help you by saying what was in the backup file you created and if you saw any errors

Comment: @RichardHuxton, I didnt notedown the logs while i restore the db, but, I tried again with the same answer by deleting the docker and created again, it got worked, thanks