# Docker for Postgresql database with data import

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to create a Docker for a PostgreSQL database and to import some data into it.
I have followed the official documentation.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:14.10

#Set env vars
ENV PGDATA=/var/pgdata
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

# Copy backup to container
COPY opr.dump /opr.dump
COPY entrypoint2.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/entrypoint2.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

The entrypoint script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Create the Postgres database 
createdb opr 

# Extract the schema and data from the backup file
pg_restore -U postgres -d opr /opr.dump
```

Everything works fine but after importing the data the container stops, both in attached and detached mode. I copied the ENTRYPOINT and CMD from the official image but without success.

I should mention that I tried also without copying ENTRYPOINT and CMD and the container still stops.

My question is how do I make the container not stop after importing the data?

Comment: [Backup/Restore a dockerized PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718706/backup-restore-a-dockerized-postgresql-database) discusses several paths, though a little more focused on using `docker exec psql` after the database container is started up.  The important detail here is that you can't run `pg_restore` until the database is actually running, which makes it hard to run in an entrypoint script.  The stock entrypoint script has logic to handle this, which [@ABWassim's answer](/a/77698769) uses.

Comment: My mistake then, thought it was some sort of entrypoint issue, I just edited my answer. Thanks for the clarification @DavidMaze !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to create a custom entrypoint script that did the trick.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:14.10

#Set env vars
ENV PGDATA=/var/pgdata
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

# Create a directory to store PostgreSQL data and logs
RUN mkdir -p ${PGDATA} /tmp /var/log/postgresql && chown -R postgres:postgres ${PGDATA} /tmp /var/log/postgresql

WORKDIR /data

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

# Copy the entrypoint script to the container
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Copy backup to container
COPY opr.dump /opr.dump

# Set the user to run the container
USER postgres

# Run the entrypoint script
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The entrypoint script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize the PostgreSQL data directory
initdb -D ${PGDATA}

#change hba_conf
echo "host all all all trust" >> /var/pgdata/pg_hba.conf

# Start PostgreSQL in the background
pg_ctl -D ${PGDATA} -l /var/log/postgresql/logfile start

# Wait for PostgreSQL to start
wait_postgresql() {
  while ! pg_isready -q; do
    echo "Waiting for PostgreSQL to start..."
    sleep 1
  done
}
wait_postgresql

# Create the Postgres database 
createdb opr 

# Extract the schema and data from the backup file
pg_restore -U postgres -d opr /opr.dump

# Keep PostgreSQL running
tail -f /var/log/postgresql/logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy your `entrypoint2.sh` script in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, as according to [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (see section **Initialization scripts**)

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived
> from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d [...] it will run any executable *.sh
> scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts found in that
> directory to do further initialization before starting the service.

Therefore no need to override the `ENTRYPOINT` and the `CMD`.

EDIT : looks like you will have to do it after the container starts, like David Maze pointed out.

Comment: I did that and the container still stops. That's why I copied ENTRYPOINT and CMD.

Comment: Take a look at David Maze's comment on your post, he actually has the right answer.

Comment: The important combination of this answer and my comment is that the `postgres` image's entrypoint already has logic to start a temporary database server, run the init script(s), and then restart the "real" database.  Putting the script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, or just the dump file if it's in SQL-statement format (make sure to name it `*.sql`), should work.